# Why did Kim Yeon stay in Jinyowon?

Tags: alchemy-of-souls

When Jinyowon was attacked, Maidservant Kim Yeon helped Jin Ho-gyeong get into Jinyowon proper to protect the relics.
However, Maidservant Kim insisted on staying in Jinyowon with Jin Ho-gyeong and told Park Jin to seal the door with her inside.

Now, we know that Kim could have left, because Ho-gyeong would not have told her to do so otherwise. It is not clear what support she could provide, either: since she was not a mage, much less a Jinyowon priestess, she could not help Ho-gyeong hold back the relics.

As such, why did Kim choose to stay in Jinyowon?